# Is there any way to use a function to mock a class `class IntToString extends (Int =>String)`?

Tags: scala, mocking

I defined a class which extends a function type:

```
class Action1 extends (String => String) {
  def apply(s:String) = s + "!"
}
```

It can be used in other methods:

```
class Action2(action1: Action1) extends (String => String) {
  def apply(n:String) = {
     val all = (action1 andThen toUpper)
     all(n)
  }
  private def toUpper(s:String) = s.toUpperCase
}
```

I can write unit tests for `Action2` with mocks:

```
 val action1 = mock[Action1]
 action1.apply(anyString) returns "sss"
 action2.andThen(any) returns ???      // I don't want to mock this

 val action2 = new Action2(action1)
 val result = action2("aa")
 result must beEqual("SSS")
```

You can see I need to mock both `apply` and `andThen`, which is a little bit boring.

If I can just use a function to mock `action1`, that will be great, like:

```
 val action2 = new Action2(_ => "sss")
 val result = action2("aa")
 result must beEqual("SSS")
```

Which is not compiled because `_ => "sss"` can't be converted to `Action1`. If I change `Action2` as:

```
class Action2(action1: String => String) extends (String => String)
```

It will be compiled but I will lose the hint of `Action1` type.

If there any way to keep the type still be `Action1`, and a simple function like `_ => "sss"` to do the mocking?

Comment: `Action2` seems right. Other way would be implicit conversion, which can be me too implicit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Action1` is a subclass of Function1 and therefore the following does not compile:

```
val f: (String => String) = ...
val a: Action1 = f                  // Does not compile
```

In order to pass anything else but a real `Action1` to `Action2` you have two options:

1. use code generation tools to override `apply` of `Action1`, or
2. change the constructor of `Action2`.

For option 1 you could for example use Mockito's [spy feature](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13):

```
val action1 = new Action1
val spy = Mockito.spy(action1)
Mockito.when(spy.apply(org.mockito.Matchers.anyString)).thenReturn("sss")

val action2 = new Action2(spy)
val result = action2("aa")
result must beEqual("SSS")
```

For option 2 you could for example accept `String => String`:

```
class Action2(action1: String => String) extends (String => String) { ... }
```

possibly aliased:

```
type Action = (String => String)

class Action1 extends Action {
  def apply(s:String) = s + "!"
}

class Action2(action1: Action) extends Action {
  def apply(n:String) = {
    val all = (action1 andThen toUpper)
    all(n)
  }
  private def toUpper(s:String) = s.toUpperCase
}

val action2 = new Action2((s: String) => "sss")
val result = action2("aa")
result must beEqual("SSS")
```

or introduce a trait:

```
trait Action extends (String => String)

class Action1 extends Action { ... same as above ... }

class Action2(action1: Action) extends Action { ... same as above ...}

def mockedAction1(r: String) = new Action { def apply(s:String) = r }

val action2 = new Action2(mockedAction1("sss"))
val result = action2("aa")
result must beEqual("SSS")
```